# How to set object element dynamically in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
filterForElement: string       
constructor(
        private api: someApiService) { }    
        someInitFunction(params:any) {
            this.filterForElement = params.filterForElement // Value is available onece component is initialize.
          }
        onChangeDrop() {
        this.api.setFilterModel({'state': {filterType: "text", type: "equals", filter: valueToUse}})
        }
```

here instead of state I want to replace with the `filterForElement` value.

Comment: Use `filterForElement` instead of 'state'?

Comment: @NicholasK I tried this way but it throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
this.api.setFilterModel({this.filterForElement: {filterType: "text", type: "equals", filter: valueToUse}})
```